# Copy Constructor Calling

Tags: c++

I am having confusion that why copy constructor function, which I have explicitly defined, is not called when I create object in that function and return it. 
Like in:

```
ABC function()
{
ABC a;
return a;
}
```

However, when i return the object of function argument copy constructor is called. It is running perfectly.
Like in:

```
ABC function2(const ABC &ab)
{
    return ab;
}
```

But I have issue in above, as it is said that when a function returns a object by value then copy constructor is called.

Please check whole code:

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class ABC
{
public:
ABC()
{
cout<<"\nDefault constructor";  
}
ABC(const ABC &ac) // copy constructor
{
cout<<"\nCopy constructor called";
}


ABC function()
{
ABC a;
return a;// why here copy constructor is not called?
}

ABC function2(const ABC &ab)
{
    return ab;// here copy constructor is calling correctly. No problem!.
}



}; 


int main()
{
ABC a, b;
b=a.function();
b=a.function2(a);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Tip: you can and should use a free tool such as **AStyle** to format your code before posting, e.g. systematic indentation. Many programmers' editors can also do that.

Comment: Thank you dear. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard allows some copy constructor calls to be optimized away, or as the standard calls it, **elided**, even if the copy constructor in question has a side effect such as outputting some text. The number of constructor and destructor calls must still match up. But e.g. the object that's returned from a function can be constructed directly in storage provided by the calling site, which is called RVO, *Return Value Optimization*.

In effect copy constructors are *assumed* to only copy, and nothing else, regardless of what they actually do.

---

In your first example,

```
ABC function()
{
    ABC a;
    return a;// why here copy constructor is not called?
}
```

… RVO can be applied, and with your compiler and compiler options, it is evidently applied.

---

With your second example,

```
ABC function2(const ABC &ab)
{
    return ab;// here copy constructor is calling correctly. No problem!.
}
```

… RVO cannot be applied because the `ab` object has already been constructed when the function body executes.

Comment: minor pedantic point but this is actually NRVO - Named Return Value Optimisation.

Comment: @T33C: The terminology has evolved, but I see no purpose in tracking that evolution. If you're interested in the history the RVO term probably originated with a g++ language extension, quite different from the above. RVO is a descriptive term, it says directly what this is about. I think insisting on silly terms like NRVO is just as counter-productive as some (silly) folks' insistence on a distinction between template function and function template, say, or arguing that const references don't exist (because they fail to grok that it's a reference to const).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  : I already gave you +1 for a good answer. RVO was a compiler optimisation introduced before NRVO. For example, my compiler only introduced NRVO in 2005. The rules concerning when either optimisation can be used are different. The OP is probably not concerned but considering your answer is accepted it may as well be accurate.

Comment: @T33C: Thanks. But as far as I'm concerned the [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) is correct. And I go back much further than 2005. More like Walter. :) Essentially you have a false dichotomy here. RVO is historically the general term, that includes the special case NRVO, where a named local variable (not formal argument) is returned. Another special case is return of temporary.